# Touchpad appears disabled and does not install - Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, touchpad

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on an Acer Aspire 5. My touchpad is no longer installed (let alone works). The cursor is static (unless I use a USB mouse). Until today, the touchpad worked as per normal.
`Xinput` shows no "touchpad".

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse                 id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer Wireless Radio Control               id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD User Facing: HD User Facing            id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Also, in the Settings / Mouse & Touchpad, there are only options for the mouse. The USB mouse works fine.

The issue is that I also have no touchpad when I dual boot into Windows 10. So I suspect this is a "computer" problem rather than an "operating system" problem. I couldn't see any options to initialize the touchpad in the UEFI menu.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See if Acer has a Hardware Diagnostic app you can run. Maybe take your laptop to a local repair shop.

Comment: Could be as simple as a loose connector on the touchpad. As you state, your use of dual-boot showed it's likely *hardware*, not OS or software. For a third test, you could try booting from a Linux USB, though I don't expect that to work, either. Has anyone spilled a drink on the laptop, lately?